# Make duo-tone illustrations by seperating colors

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor, light

I'm working on a workflow to make *duotone* illustrations. I like to work with emission shaders for this, because they eliminate all lightbounces, thereby it requires almost no rendertime and gives me a vector-like illustration. In the image below I put a Fresnel Node in the Mixshader to seperate colors, but what I actually want is to replace this Node for the information of the lighting in the scene. Got any ideas?

I also tried to use a Toon node and a Glossy node with roughness to 0, but I really like the Emission shader because the color isn't affected by background or lighting. Maybe there is a way to convert a material node to color data and to set a colorramp on that?
[image: Node set-up]

Comment: It's unclear to me what you actually need: those two sentences seems contradictory: *"I really like the Emission shader because the color isn't affected by background or lighting"* **and** *"what I actually want is to replace this Node for the information of the lighting in the scene"*. You may want to search for NPR in Google/Youtube, there's a lot of tutorials on that. Here's one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TpWI2rU8iF0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to calculate scene lighting, try shader to RGB node.

[image]